# MySQL 5.6 showing wrong "second_behind_master"

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, mysql-5.6

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.10.7.98
                  Master_User: replication
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000032
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 277431436
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000039
                Relay_Log_Pos: 143474118
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000031
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 963696099
              Relay_Log_Space: 530952469
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 98
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: /mnt/vol1/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: updating
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here second_behind_master is showing 0 even currently slave is having Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000031 and master is having Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000032.

Comment: There are a number of bugs in 5.6 related to seconds behind master. Have you searched bugs.mysql.com for these? Are you running the most recent 5.6 point-release?

Comment: I am using Master Server Version 5.0.95-log
and slave server version 5.6.17-log.

Comment: I've seen other strange issues appear when replicating from 5.0 to 5.6. MySQL officially does not support replication between versions more than one major version apart (which just means they didn't test it, and won't be responsible for unpredictable effects). I suggest you get both master and slave on the same version.